# How can positional encodings including a sine operation be linearly transformable for any offset?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematics, linear-algebra

In the paper ["Attention is all you need"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf) the authors add a positional encoding to each token in the sequence (section 3.5). The following encoding is chosen:

$ PE(pos, 2dim) = sin(pos / 10000 ^ {2dim/d_{model}} ) $

$ PE(pos, 2dim+1) = cos(pos / 10000 ^ {2dim/d_{model}} ) $

The text states that "for any fixed offset $k$, $PE(pos+k)$ can be represented as a linear function of $PE(pos)$". This did not seem obvious due to me due to the nonlinearity of the sine function. Other resources like [Attention is all you need Explained](http://mlexplained.com/2017/12/29/attention-is-all-you-need-explained/) mention this property but do not go deeper into it.

I decided to experiment with this by attempting to map a number of outputs from the $PE(pos)$ function to outputs with a given offset $k$.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def PE_even(pos, dim):
    """ This corresponds to the 2dim state. """
    size = 10000
    d_Model = 512
    return np.sin(pos / (size ** (2 * dim / d_Model)))

positions = pd.Series(np.arange(0, 1000))

k = 10
a = positions.apply(lambda p: PE_even(p, 64))
b = positions.apply(lambda p: PE_even(p + k, 64))

X = a.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = b.values
r = LinearRegression()
r.fit(X, y)
r.score(X, y)
```

However, no offset nor any range of numbers in these dimensions yields a suitable fit. As $k$ increases and the sine waves resulting from the $PE(pos)$ function get out of sync, the correlation of the transformation and the truth decreases. Even using simple neural networks with and without linearities does not yield a good fit.

Did I misapprehend the statement in the paper, or is my code or understanding of the underlying math here faulty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I elected to ask this question on the Mathematics Stack Exchange and I thought it prudent to add the answer here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3119882

From what I have learned from [@Servaes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30382/servaes), who was kind enough to answer the question, there is a function

$\operatorname{PE}(\text{pos}+k,2d)=\operatorname{PE}(\text{pos},2d)\cos(k/c^d)+\operatorname{PE}(\text{pos},2d+1)\sin(k/c^d)$

that allows for the property of transforming any positional encoding into one with a given offset. However, due to the required use of the sin() and cos() functions this is not a linear transformation.